# PHP and variable variables ($$) syntax

Tags: php, variable-variables

Before upgrading to PHP 7, I had this code and it **returned true**

```
var_dump(isset($$_SESSION['payment']) );
var_dump(is_object($$_SESSION['payment'])); 
var_dump($_SESSION['payment']); // string 'moneyorder'
```

After upgrading to PHP 7, I rewrote the same code inside a class, but now it **returns false**

```
var_dump(isset(${$_SESSION['payment']})); 
var_dump(is_object(${$_SESSION['payment']}));
var_dump($_SESSION['payment']); // string 'moneyorder'
```

Do you have an idea why ?

Thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION["payment"])` show?

Comment: Just a precision : Before the data was in a simple files and now the same datas are in class.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['payment']);  See above

Comment: So does your original code run in PHP 7 or not? Because it seems like your question should say "After upgrading to PHP 7, rewriting some lines of code, and putting them in a class, it works differently."

Comment: I suggest you redesign your code so you don't need variable variables. Anything you do with them should probably be done using a associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Note [the PHP documentation for superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) contains this warning:

> **Note: Variable variables**
>
> Superglobals cannot be used as variable variables inside functions or class methods.

Save it to a local variable instead:

```
$payment = $_SESSION['payment'];
var_dump(isset(${$payment})); 
var_dump(is_object(${$payment}));
```